# Can not delete or update error in postman express mongoose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

I have written a code to update and delete with json and testing with postman it shows like below
[image]here is my code

[image]

please give me a solution for this matter..

Comment: I change "  res.status(200).send({status:"notice Deleted",noticeId:update });" to this one " res.status(200).send({status:"notice Deleted" });" But its not working

Comment: Are you sure the mentioned path is correct. because the error suggest that it can't find the url. check the port number once again if that's a correct ome

Comment: try to change `:id` with fixed string, e.g `/deleteNotice/a` and call it again with postman. if it's the same, you need to show your routing (update the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you show your routing

And after that, change your define noticeId to `let noticeId = req.params.id`

Because of you defined the route is `/deleteNotice/:id` with `id` is your params

Answer (score 1):

the req.params.  should be the same like you write it in the path ("../:id")
so your code must be like this : `let noticeId = req.params.id`
or you change the path like this : `router.route('/deleteNotice/:noticeId')` and keeping this : `let noticeId = req.params.noticeId`